# duplicate records received through API(rest)

Tags: api, rest, testing, web-api-testing

I am Tester and i have api to test with rest request,we have validation for api request with duplicate records is not allowed with email id,but some times application accept duplicate records,what is possible reason??

Comment: I have reproduced this issue with parameterization using jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be a application issue, may be in certain scenarios, discuss with your developers on this to get a better understanding